# LinkLabel in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am tasked with adding a hyperlink into one of our PropertyGrids.  I assumed this would be a trivial task (oops) but it seems far from it.  I am running out of ideas.  Has anybody done this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well... Have you ever seen it done before? There is at least one compete drop in replacement for PropertyGrid that offers this, though - visualhint.com

Comment: In case anybody else is trying to do this, Marc is obviously correct that it isn't really possible.  That being said, you can get some of the functionality by capturing the selected row changed event and using that to open the hyperlink.  Unfortunately, this fires on the selection of either the key or the value, and it doesn't provide any of the nice coloring/underling functionality that a normal link would provide...